# can find button tag in selenium python using find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath, web-crawler

HTML:

```
<button aria-expanded="false" class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline link" data-ember-action data-ember-action-2611="2611">
```

Python:

```
 buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(u'//button[@class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline link"]')
    print(buttons)
    for degree in buttons:
        degree.click()
```

there are two button with the same tag written above but it does not access any of them. It just print the empty list.

Comment: Have you used any implicit wait? Are you sure about the xpath?

Comment: yeah i wait till the page is full loaded but still not working

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code. The first trouble shoot is the implicit time and next is the xpath. Since, you have mentioned you have waited, can you cross verify the xpath again?. Also give us the complete html dom

Comment: <button aria-expanded="false" class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline link" data-ember-action data-ember-action-2611="2611">

Comment: i've checked the path several time still not get it :(

Comment: Ahmad in the html you have provided, there are only open tags and no close tags. Can you give the html dom of the complete page highlighting both the elements that needs to be identified?

Comment: <span class="svg-icon-wrap">…</span> </button> there is only some text and this span tag in button

Comment: Can you please update your question to the exact HTML code (along with the span elements), rather than the comments, so that the question looks more clear.

Comment: i already type that in comment

Comment: try (//button[@class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline link"])[1]

Comment: index out of range!

Comment: Add the screenshot of HTML tab in Developer Tools, with the buttons highlighted

Comment: is you element inside `svg` tag?

Comment: i dont think so.